# Interpreted programming language checker

Tags: python

I was reviewing Python materials and it was written that it is a interpreted language. There was a diagram follow presented as `source code` -> `checker` -> `interpreter` -> `output`. What is the checker?

Comment: That's... **really** not a good (or even remotely accurate) explanation of the process. Python is parsed to an AST, and then compiled to bytecode, which is then interpreted. The parser implicitly checks syntax validity, but to describe it as a "checker" is really off-base.

Comment: Well, I'm starting my advanture with programming so I might not be in the possion to judge. It's from a paper presented during MIT classes. It supposed to be an introduction for people with no programming experience.

Comment: Just because its an intro course doesn't mean they should be teaching less then accurate information.

Comment: ...how far MIT has fallen, from intro-level courses based on [SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/).

Comment: I see your points. So you would not recommend to watch the classes ?